# What model should be returned from IDataProvider.model()

Tags: wicket

Given the IDataProvider

```
public interface IDataProvider<T> extends IDetachable {

    IModel<T> model(T object);
}
```

What model should I return here? In the javadoc there is written:

> Callback used by the consumer of this data provider to wrap objects retrieved from #iterator(int, int} with a model (usually a detachable one).

Let's say I have a LoadableDetachableModel that loads list of objects from a database. This model is the input for the dataProvider. Why should I wrap each object in a detachable model again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-serializable objects it should be LDM - so they can be reloaded on subsequent request. For serializable objects you can use plain Model<T>, if you don't mind the object being stored in the session.

The model you provide will be available for the populated row, so when you work in row context, e.g. some AJAX update of label, you just load single object from db instead whole list during rendering phase.

My usual approach is to directly load the entities and provide iterator over them without wrapping them in the model. Then I provide wrapping LDM for entity in #model().

Comment: I think I still don't understand the wicket model approach. When it's serialized etc... If I have LDM<List<Object>> as an input for dataProvider, then it's detached. So why should I care about LDM for individual row models, they are obtained from the LDM<List<Object>>.

Comment: With your approach when the page is re-rendered, it loads all row models from DB one by one. That's very slow, doesn't it?

Comment: When the page is re-rendered, the IDataProvider is asked again for all available rows. But if you click on a component in a row - e.g. for selection, deletion, opening, ... - only the model for the single row is accessed.

Comment: Basically your approach can be valid, but the interface IDataProvider was designed for use cases that I/svenmeier described. In those, model is propagated to the row level and stored there.

Answer (score 0):

You said that a LDM is the input for the dataprovider. Which object handles pagination in your case?

We often call our services directly to retrieve the size and the objects. We use the model as intended. Load 1 single object.